# Fallback Avatar Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

If the user doesnt have an auto generated avatar, how can i fall back to a default image?

This is my code.

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<img class="avatar" src="'. wsl_get_user_custom_avatar ($current_user->ID) .'" alt="avatar"> Welcome '.$current_user->display_name.', Please help our community grow by liking and sharing! <br> <a class="logout" href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Logout</a>'; }
    else {
        echo '<h2>1 Click Login</h2>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php do_action( 'wordpress_social_login' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Change the path of default avatar the one you like...

```
    <?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$avatarPath = wsl_get_user_custom_avatar ($current_user->ID)?wsl_get_user_custom_avatar ($current_user->ID):'http://img.thehobbyblogger.com/2012/08/mystery-man-avatar.png';
            echo '<img class="avatar" src="'.$avatarPath.'" alt="avatar"> Welcome '.$current_user->display_name.', Please help our community grow by liking and sharing! <br> <a class="logout" href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Logout</a>'; }
        else {
            echo '<h2>1 Click Login</h2>';
        }
        ?>
        <?php do_action( 'wordpress_social_login' ); ?>
```